# logout stuck - exit only with Ctrl+C

Tags: centos7, logout

When I logout from Linux server running CentOS7. 
It stuck.
I run the ps command to see which processes are running, I saw:

> dbus-launch --autolaunch XXX --binary-syntax --close-stderr
> /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 6 --print-address 8 --session
> /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
> /usr/libexec/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session

After it was stuck for a long time, I press ^C. 
It cause a the logout to finish (I logout from the server) and the above processes killed.

Why it happen. What can I do to solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had / full 100%.

After I clean it the problem solved